# how do I store user information on a mobile device

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile

I'm developing a phone App on Adobe Flex mobile ( flex 4.6) in actionscript 3.

This app will have a username and password so that the user may log in ot it. But I want to have his username and password stored somewhere so that when he opens the app, if he was signed in last time, it'll retain that information and he will not have to sign in again.

Sonce this is my first phone app, I have no clue, but if you can direct me in the right way I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

~Myy

Answer (score 1):

For username and password I would probably use [EncryptedLocalStore](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html).